# How do I profile memory usage in my project

Tags: c#

Are there any good, **free** tools to profile memory usage in C# ?

Details:
I have a visualization project that uses quite large collections. I would like to check which parts of this project - on the data-processing side, or on the visualization side - use most of the memory, so I could optimize it.
I know that when it comes to computing size of the collection the case is quite simple and I can do it on my own. But there are also certain elements for which I cannot estimate the memory usage so easily.
The memory usage is quite big, for example processing a file of size 35 MB my program uses a little bit more than 250 MB of RAM.

Comment: How are you measuring that memory usage at the moment by the way?

Comment: Just checking in the memory usage in the task manager. My coworkers informed me that for large datasets it uses even 1.5GB of memory and sometimes causes "out of memory" exception, so I need to find a way to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success using RedGate's [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm). It is also worth reading [Brad Abrams blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/) where he has [talked about profiling memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/03/17/398060.aspx)

Comment: @Ed worth every penny in my experience, though; and there is an evaluation version which could be used for a short term project

Comment: Not **free** (as he ask for) though

Comment: @Alfred the trial is free, which may suffice, though. It's certainly more usable than the free CLR Profiler available from the Microsoft website

Comment: Although it's not free it seems that this solution would be the best. I only hope that 14 days of trial would be enough for me to get rid of my problems with memory usage. Thanks!

Comment: @Gacek It was long enough to convince me to fork out for a copy :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm amazed noone has mentioned the free [CLR Profiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler) from Microsoft!

I didn't know of this tool until recently. I had a bug that made my program keep allocating more and more memory. The CLR Profiler can pinpoint memory-allocating "hot spots" in your program.

I identified the line of code responsible for the leak, within 15-20 minutes of installing the profiler.

Basically, it instruments your code and runs it with some profiling (which slows down your code considerably, 10x-100x are the official figures I think).

You run a certain workload for a certain amount of time, and you can then see which places in your code that allocated how much memory (and how much was freed versus how much was retained etc.).

Check it out at: https://clrprofiler.codeplex.com/

Also, here is a tutorial on how to use the tool: http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2009/03/13/speedy-c-part-4-using---and-understanding---clr.aspx

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/features/index.html#Memory_profiling) is also good. I have used both the RedGate and JetBrains products and they both do a very good job of identifying the bottlenecks and leaks.