# Memory usage after running a long job

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

I have a long process running (importing data from an XML file, it can run hours, the XML file size could be around 25-30MB), and after the end of this process I have a huge memory usage (that is not liberated after the end of the ran).

And I experienced some Exceptions like :

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its
>   dependencies. Not enough storage is available to process this command.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

Regarding to the answer here [Not enough storage is available to process this command in VisualStudio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995906/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command-in-visualstudio-2008), It's because I don't have enough contiguous space virtual memory available

When I look to Task Manager, I see 875.1 MB used by my IIS Express, how can I profile that ? 
In my code I am manipulating document (images, pdf), but when I read them from disk I am always inside an `using` statement

I want to know/understand why IIS use 875.1 MB after the end of my job. There is any tools to analyse the memory use, specially a dump file postmortem ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for [How do I profile memory usage in my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629034/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-my-project)?

Comment: @SirRufo sorry if it is unclear, what I wanted to know is if there is anyway to diagnostic the data in memory, I thought about something that I can run post execution. But maybe I should try to run a debug diagnostic tool such redgate but as the process is too long I wanted to avoid it initially

Comment: thanks @dbc I will try to use CLR Profiler

Comment: Switch to 64 bit to solve at least the address space limitation causing that exception. Otherwise, if there is a memory leak it cannot be found without code.

Comment: Maybe also see [Analyze .NET Framework memory issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342825.aspx#BKMK_Collect_memory_snapshots) and [What is a dump, and how do I create one?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugger/2009/12/30/what-is-a-dump-and-how-do-i-create-one/) and [Analyzing memory dump to find leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522329/analyzing-memory-dump-to-find-leak).

Comment: @rad Please edit your question and add a sentence that ends with a question mark **?** to make it clear what you are really asking for. Do not add this in the comments section. Until now the question is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you @dbc again looks like Analyse .NET Framework memory issues is what I was looking for, I will try it tonight and I will let you know.